# Android - Button onclick no errors but getting "App stopped working"

Tags: java, android

I want to open my app store link of my app on image click. On mainactivity file, inside the OnCreate, I have added following

```
    ImageView Button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=APPNAME"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And on the layout file, here is my image;

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                ads:srcCompat="@drawable/write009" />
```

Where I am doing mistake ?

UPDATE: Here is what I got from the logcat after debug with virtual device

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{antivirus.android.APPNAME/com.APPNAME.activities.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a 
null object reference
```

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: Please post your logs/stacktrace

Comment: How can I see the stacktrace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173, https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: I have updated my question with log info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Without the crash log its hard to guess the problem but I think that you should not use the `addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)` in your intent.

```
ImageView button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=APPNAME"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="232dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:src="@drawable/write009" />
```

change  `ads:srcCompat` to `android:src`.

Answer (score 1):

According to LogCat, your variable `Button` is null - findViewById() couldn't find `R.id.imageView5`. Are you sure you edited the right layout file? Are you loading this layout file on the beggining of your Activity `onCreate()` using `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name)`?

Also, you could try changing the variable name to lowercase `button`, maybe it clashes with class `Button` (I doubt this, but strange stuff happens)